# Android different menu options for tablet vs phone

Tags: android

I wanna know if it's possible to manage different menu options for phones versus tablets on android. Because of small screen I'd like to keep using only 2 options on toolbar and others will go to "spinner option", but on tablet I can use more of them. I know Android is doing this automatically using `ifRoom` but maybe there is an option to set different `menu.xml` file for w600dp and w820dp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not?
I've created folders manually in /res folder, syncronize folder in Studio and here is the result:
[image]

I created folders in res:
[image]

and then put my menu.xml there.

Comment: Under `/res` you created `/menu_bp_add` and how did you mention that first file is for phones and the others for tablet?